# Is $x + x = 2x,\ x \in \mathbb{F}$ for all fields $\mathbb{F}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

### The question

Obviously, a field has a $1$ and a $0$ element, the former being neutral regarding addition, the latter being neutral regarding the multiplication operator. Additionally, we know that in the best-known numerical fields, e.g. $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, holds $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}: x + x = 2x$.

Does this and similar behavior ($x + x + x = 3x$, $\frac{3}{2} \cdot x = x + \frac{1}{2} \cdot x$, $\dots$) hold for all fields $\mathbb{F}$? Apart from the fact that the distributive property holds, I can't see any connection between the $+$ and $\cdot$ operation in a given field $\mathbb{F}$.

### The reason I'm asking

I'm asking this question because I originally thought that this would *not* hold in every field. For one thing, how would you know which element represents e.g. the $2 \in \mathbb{R}$ in $x + x = 2x$? What would guarantee that such an element even exists?

But looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883946/616935) and its answer, it seems there must be a way to relate the well-known $\frac{1}{2}$ in e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ to some element in any body $\mathbb{F}$. The exact way they've come to the solutions there isn't quite clear, but I'd do it by solving the system of equations
$$
X_{ij} = A_{ij} + B_{ij}\\
X_{ji} = A_{ij} - B_{ij}\\
\Updownarrow\\
X_{ij} = A_{ij} + B_{ij}\\
X_{ij} + X_{ji} = A_{ij} + A_{ij} \overset{?}{=} 2 A_{ij}
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "2" in the question in the title? If you mean $1 + 1$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity for $F$, then the answer is "yes" by the distributive property. If you mean $2 \in \Bbb R$, then the question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Regarding $\frac{3}{2}x=x+\frac{1}{2}x$, in some fields (the ones of characteristic $2$) you cannot divide by $2$, and there is no good way to give meaning to $\frac{3}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very interesting! Hoping for it to be a quick answer, wouldn't this allow us to *disprove* the theorem I linked? Consider the $\mathbb{F}_2$, then there should be no way of writing
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
as a sum of a symmetric and a skew symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, consider a commutative ring $R$ with unity $1$.

For $n\geq 1$, the $n$-fold of $x\in R$ is defined inductively as
$$1\cdot x = x,\quad (n+1)\cdot x = n\cdot x + x.$$
Write $nx$ instead of $n\cdot x$.

Moreover, $0x = 0$, since $0x = (x+(-x))x = x^2-x^2=0$.

For $n<0$, the $n$-fold of $x\in R$ is defined as
$$n\cdot x = (-n)(-x).$$

Example: $2x = x+x$ and $(-2)x = (-x) + (-x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The distributive property is exactly what makes this true. Note that $2$ is defined as $1+1$, so we have $2x = (1+1)x = x + x$. Try using a similar method to prove the similar results you mentioned.

Comment: I see, I was lacking that definition. Then obviously $\frac{1}{2}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2 = (1 + 1)$, and $3 = (1+1+1) = 2 + 1$. Thank you!